# Search causes an error, like this Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Search' of undefined at eval (data-source.js:14)

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

[image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Search' of undefined]

```
import clubs from "./clubs.js";

class DataSource {
  static searchClub(keyword) {
    fetch(
        `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=dd08fe3c&s=${keyword}`
      )
      .then(response => {
        response.json()
      })
      .then(responseJson => {
        const movies = responseJson.Search;
        let cards = '';
        movies.forEach(m => cards += showCards(m));
        const cardMovie = document.querySelector('.card-movie');
        cardMovie.innerHTML = cards;
      });
  }
}

export default DataSource;
```

note: data-source.js

Comment: You have posted your API key publicly – you should remove this from your post and regenerate your API key on omdbapi.com

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not getting any response from the API. You have null in responseJSON variable and you are trying to access Search on undefined that's why you are getting this error.
Try to

```
console.log(responseJSON);
```

and see is there any value. if not may be something is wrong with API endpoint.